# Is every compact contractible subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to a closed ball of some dimension?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

**Question**: Is every compact contractible subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to a closed ball of some dimension?

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55114/are-contractible-open-sets-in-mathbbrn-homeomorphic-to-mathbb-rn) doesn't quite answer my question because it is about open sets.

Comment: Join three unit intervals in an endpoint to form a space shaped like the letter Y

Answer (score 3):

No!! For example consider Mazur manifold (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold) which can be embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ [to see this, take double of it, which is $S^4$, and remove a point]. But it is not homeomorphic to any ball as it's boundary is not a sphere.